# wordpress: add custom meta-box to pages overview not only to posts/pages?

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I know how to add meta boxes to pages/posts/custom_post_type ($post_type) pages:

```
$screens = array( 'post', 'page' );

foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

    add_meta_box(
        'myplugin_sectionid',
        __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'myplugin_meta_box_callback',
        $screen
    );
}
```

but how do i add a meta box to the pages-overview? i need a link-list there to some special pages ...

I know there are plugins who can do this:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/screenshots/
but only on posts/pages edit screen, like any tutorial i have found.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add stuff to a column in that screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23564239/1287812) using the filter `"manage_edit-{$cpt}_columns"` and the action `"manage_{$cpt}_posts_custom_column"`:

[image]

And it is possible to catch form submissions using:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php',  'load_edit_so_23561386' );

function load_edit_so_23561386()
{
    global $typenow;
    $cpt = 'post';
    if( $typenow !== $cpt )
        return;

    if( isset( $_POST['YOUR-FORM'] ) )
        do_your_stuff();
}
```

**But** as there are **multiple** posts (virtually 999), it's much better to use AJAX, but that's a whole other story.